# ownCloud Desktop Client Theming

Tags: cmake, nsis, owncloud

I have been trying to build the desktop client for about a week now so that I can dig in and try to mess with some theming and turn off some features I wont be needing. In the process I have run into numerous issues and have managed to resolve them in one way or another. I have a VM running openSUSE and I have downloaded the source file ownCloudClient-2.3.2.tar.xz file and unzipped it all into my home/jwarren/client folder. I then ran:

```
cd admin/win/docker
docker build . -t owncloud-client-win32:
```

Which I was able to get through. Now I am on the second command:

```
docker run -v "$PWD:/home/user/client" owncloud-client-win32: \
/home/user/client/admin/win/docker/build.sh client/ $(id -u)
```

Here I am getting almost to the end and then I receive this error message which I cant figure out how to resolve.

CPack Error: Problem running NSIS command "user/bin/makensis"
CPack Error: Problem Compressing Directory

Can anyone help me out with this? Or maybe point me in the direction of better instructions for the ownCloud Desktop Client theming. I noticed that once you get it installed properly there is no instructions explaining where anything is to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a comprehensive guide to build the Windows client using the cross-compilation toolchain in the Dockerfile some time ago in ownCloud's central: https://central.owncloud.org/t/error-using-docker-to-build-the-windows-client/5107/5

What you're probably missing out is **the git-submodule initialization**; i.e. running `git submodule update --init` on your unzipped repository. You need these to bundle on the installer some [pre-compiled binaries](https://github.com/owncloud/owncloud-client-binary/) used by the shell integrations.

Also, on a side note, there was some problems last month with mingw toolchain compiler (gcc7) - in case you get some dll error after installing the client with your self-generated installer, refer to https://central.owncloud.org/t/building-the-windows-installer/8403/4 for an snapshot of a fully working Docker image to use instead of your self-built.

About the docs to build your own theme: those can be found in https://doc.owncloud.org/branded_clients/branded_desktop_client/index.html (for enterprise installations of ownCloud) - and for an unsupported version, you can also check the source in
https://github.com/owncloud/client/blob/master/src/libsync/theme.cpp for some hints about what settings can be overwritten from there.